# Javascript: enumerate global vars

Tags: javascript

```
a = 123; // becomes global var

var b = 234; // local var

function f() {} // local func

g = function() {} // got a global func
```

now how to print `a` and `g` (and all other global variables to date), but not `b` and `f` (and other local variables at the moment).

```
console.log(this)// is not working.
```

EDIT:
    Suggestion to use "window" variable will only work in the browser, but embedded Javascript or Node.js do not have a "window" variable.

Comment: `console.log(window);`

Comment: Object.getOwnPropertyNames(this)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about:

```
var globals = window || global;
for (var key in globals){
  console.log(window[key]);
}
```

Comment: it says "window is not defined" (I am using node.js at the moment)

Comment: i don't see atob() or escape() in that list, aren't those globals?

Comment: @dandavis they should be, I see them when i execute the code above.

Comment: do you see an alert when you run:  for (var key in window)if(key==='escape')alert(123) ? i don't see anything, but i only tried it in firefox and chrome and IE...

Comment: @dandavis sorry you are right, what i said above was misleading i actually just went `window['escape']` and assumed it would be the same.  That is very odd, I am not sure what is happening.

Comment: @marteljn: try Object.getOwnPropertyNames(window).indexOf("escape"). it's an own property as in window.hasOwnProperty("escape"), yet it's not iterated by for-in. Object.keys(window).indexOf("escape") should be -1. so where does escape() come from? some of the other ones that don't show up in keys() or getOwnPropertyNames(), like alert(), are defined on Window.prototype, which your for-loop dredges. that said, escape() is a strange beast because that's not how it's defined.

Answer (score 0):

All global variables are stored on the `window` object in a browser. Alternatively, they are stored on the `global` or `GLOBAL` object in Node.js. You can enumerate that object's keys instead, but keep in mind that it will contain much, much more than user-defined globals.

Comment: hmmm. window.hasOwnProperty('toString') is false, but toString() is not undefined. don't forget about Object.prototype!

Answer (score 0):

Globals become attached to the global object, which in a browser is the window.

```
a = 123
```

is the same as

```
window.a = 123
```

Comment: what's the global object in node.js?