# When enumerating over window object escape function is not present

Tags: javascript

This question is based off of an observation by user @dandavis in this question [Javascript: enumerate global vars](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19305371/javascript-enumerate-global-vars/19305414#19305414).

When iterating over the `window` object, `escape` is never outputted.

```
for (var key in window){
  console.log(key);
  if(key === "escape"){
    console.log("This never happens!");
  }
}
```

However, if I explicitly, write in the console:

```
window["escape"]
```

The function is outputted to the screen as expected.

Can anyone explain this anomaly?

Also, I have been testing in Chrome 30.0.1599.69 on Windows 7.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Firefox, at least, the "escape" property of `window` is not enumerable.

```
console.dir(Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(window, "escape"));
```

shows the descriptor from your browser debug console.