# Javascript: global vars go to "window" or "global" but global functions do not. Where do global fns go?

Tags: javascript, function, global, enumeration

Global variables can be found in "global" or "window" at most times.  https://stackoverflow.com/a/19305414/4808079

But global functions aren't there with them.

```
var globals = window || global

hat = "fez"

alert(globals["hat"]) // alert --> "fez"

function test() {
    alert("yay")
}

alert(globals["test"]) // alert --> "undefined"

globals["test"]()  // console --> "Uncaught TypeError: globals.test is not a function"
```

https://jsfiddle.net/yz4c62xg/2/

So where do global functions go?  Can they be accessed or enumerated like global vars?

Comment: I don't problem with your code on IE11 and Chrome.

Comment: The test function doesn't return anything. You're looking for `globals["test"]` not `globals["test"]()`.

Comment: I'm pretty sure I'm looking for the global function called test.

Comment: Where is *global* defined? Perhaps you forgot `var global = this`. Since the global object and the window object are synonymous in a browser, it doesn't make sense to write `var globals = window || global` (even if *global* refers to the global object). Just reference the global object.

Comment: Is this node? In node, variables/functions are not placed on the `global` object, they are in module scope. See https://nodejs.org/api/globals.html#globals_global. *The top-level scope is not the global scope; `var something` inside an Node.js module will be local to that module.*

Comment: @RobG So far, nowhere I've found.  It was part of the solution from the linked question, and I felt like covering all bases.

Answer (score 0):

Your code will work fine in the browser.

In node, however, variables/functions are not placed on the `global` object, they are in module scope. See https://nodejs.org/api/globals.html#globals_global.

> The top-level scope is not the global scope; `var something` inside an Node.js module will be local to that module.

Comment: I'm getting alert "undefined."  I'll try a few other browsers

Comment: Firefox and Chrome are both throwing the console error for me